# How to verify that you have enough resources at Azure

Tags: python, azure, azure-storage, azure-resource-manager, azure-resource-group

## Background

If this seems like a question with incomplete information, it is. That's because it has to do with a large project that uses Azure to automatically provision and scale and downscale a large amount of VMs, that was handed over to us by a third party, and we're having trouble understanding some issues. But I'll try my best to explain

We are using python's Azure [SDK](http://azure-sdk-for-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) to launch Azure VMs, to kill them etc. See this code used in the method that launches azure vms:

```
    #Get VMs info. do it via minimum calls to speed up things
    started_on = time.time()
    while True:
        try:
            time.sleep(5)
            vm = compute_client.virtual_machines.get(self.resource_group, vm_name)
            break
```

## Problem

Sometimes when we run this command, we get this error:

```
aioc.logic.connectors.azure:2017-08-17 08:39:45,709 | ERROR | Stop waiting for VM auto-acfinH-25 to finish
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/aioc/aioc/aioc/logic/connectors/azure.py", line 126, in start
    vm = compute_client.virtual_machines.get(self.resource_group, vm_name)
  File "/home/aioc/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/azure/mgmt/compute/compute/v2016_04_30_preview/operations/virtual_machines_operations.py", line 369, in get
    raise exp
msrestazure.azure_exceptions.CloudError: Azure Error: ResourceNotFound
Message: The Resource 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/auto-acfinH-25' under resource group 'AIOCBot' was not found.
aioc.logic.main_controller_logic:2017-08-17 08:39:45,978 | ERROR | An error occurred while checking Vm with id '599553cdc1462e3a828c66da' machine id '328'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/aioc/aioc/aioc/logic/main_controller_logic.py", line 41, in run_vm_controller
    started_vms = vmc.start(vm.machine_type, 1)
  File "/home/aioc/aioc/aioc/logic/connectors/azure.py", line 135, in start
    vm_net_interface = network_client.network_interfaces.get(self.resource_group, vm_name)
  File "/home/aioc/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/azure/mgmt/network/v2017_03_01/operations/network_interfaces_operations.py", line 171, in get
    raise exp
msrestazure.azure_exceptions.CloudError: Azure Error: ResourceNotFound
```

Upon investigation, it turns out this is happening b/c our resources at azure have maxed out (?). The way to solve this problem is by purging the said resources by using this method:

```
def cleanup_all(self):
    """
    Clean up all auto-created resources
    """
    compute_client = ComputeManagementClient(self.credentials, self.subscription_id)
    network_client = NetworkManagementClient(self.credentials, self.subscription_id)
    resource_client = ResourceManagementClient(self.credentials, self.subscription_id)

    l = resource_client.resources.list()
    for r in [r for r in l if r.name.startswith('auto-')]:
        try:
            if 'publicIPAddresses' in r.type:
                rs = network_client.public_ip_addresses.delete(self.resource_group, r.name)
                rs.wait()
            elif 'Microsoft.Network' in r.type: 
                rs = network_client.network_interfaces.delete(self.resource_group, r.name)
                rs.wait()
            elif 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines' in r.type:
                rs = compute_client.virtual_machines.delete(self.resource_group, r.name)
                rs.wait()
        except:
            log.warn("Failed to stop resource: %s with type: %s", r.name, r.type, exc_info=1)
```

Which is all awesome. However, for business reasons we cannot simply 
- create a cron job that runs this commands on a regular interval
- cannot run it in any automated fashion b/c it affects many different environments at once (ie prod/demo/stage/dev) which is too big a side affect to be fathomable.

Which means we must run this command periodically, every once in a while once we have an agreement that all envs are clear and ready.

## Question

I would like to take a look at the *resources* section inside my Azure console

[image]

and have *a way* to find out how much of my *allowed* resources I have consumed. I need to have an idea for example that: oh by the way you have consumed like 45% percent of your allowed public ips etc, and that way I know if I'm safe or if I need to run the purge command again.

Ideas?

## Update

[This page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits) discussees in detail the available limits, for example:

[image]

But it doesn't talk about how to gauge how much of these resources are currently in use or how much is left.. that's what i'm trying to find out

can someone explain what's going on?

Comment: Do you want to find the information programmatically or manual process will also do?

Comment: @GauravMantri for starters i'll be happy with manual information, although knowing how this info can be obtained programmatically is welcome as well

Comment: @abbood Firstly, this is a classic mode limit. In resource mode, you could use 60 public IP address(dynamic) by default, if you want to reach the limit, you could create a ticket.  Please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/resource-manager-core-quotas-request). The ticket is free.

Comment: @abbood You could use [sdk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure.mgmt.compute.compute.v2017_03_30.operations.usageoperations?view=azure-python) to list VM usage.

Answer (score 3):

Part answer to your question. For manual, you can find this information on Azure portal itself. Click on "Subscription", then select your subscription from the subscriptions list and then "Usage + quota".

[image]

Comment: that was too easy.. if you can give me resources (ie apis) where i can read this programmatically i'd really appreciate it! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can find them programmatically, but this is dispatched per provider:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/python/api/azure.mgmt.network.v2017_06_01.operations.usagesoperations
- https://learn.microsoft.com/python/api/azure.mgmt.storage.v2017_06_01.operations.usageoperations
- https://learn.microsoft.com/python/api/azure.mgmt.compute.compute.v2017_03_30.operations.usageoperations

For a more Event based programming, there is most probably a way to plug Event Grid and/or Logic Apps and/or Azure Monitor to be warned automatically.